# Testing of significance for a single proportion

Tags: statistics, sampling

Suppose a large number $n$ of independent Bernoullian trials is performed and $x$ successes are obtained. Suppose we wish to test the hypothesis that probability of success in each trial is $p$, assuming the hypothesis to be correct, the mean and variance of the sampling distribution of the number of success are $np$ and $npq$ respectively. Then for large $n$ $z=({x-np})/{\sqrt {npq}}$ is distributed as a standard normal variate. Hence we get $P(\vert z \vert >3)=0.0027$
Where did the $3$ come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is arbitrary, illustrating the probability with a normal distribution of being more than $3$ standard deviations from the mean in the two tails.

It could have said

- "Hence we get $P(\vert z \vert >2)=0.0455$"
- "Hence we get $P(\vert z \vert >1)=0.3173$"

or various similar things.  This is similar to the so-called [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) but with the probabilities of being in the tails rather than the middle of the distribution

Answer (score 0):

This statement uses the normal approximation to a binomial probability, which works well for sufficiently large $n$ and $p$ not too far from 1/2.

The idea is that you will reject the null hypothesis that $p = p_0$ at the 0.3% level if $|Z| > 3.$

For example, if $n = 36$ and $p_0 = 1/2,$ then you would
reject $H_0: p = 1/2,$ if you got only $X=1$ Success.

The probability that an observation from a standard normal distribution is in the interval $(-3,3)$ is about 0.997. In R:

```
diff(pnorm(c(-3,3)))
[1] 0.9973002
```

Alternatively, perhaps you can find a printed table of the standard normal PDF that goes that far out from $0.$

Also, perhaps google the Empirical Rule.

Comment: My question is why that 3. Let me tell what I’m thinking. The hypothesis that each success having the same probability p will never look like a normal curve and hence should lie outside the normal curve. Is that right

Comment: I think they are using a normal approximation to the binomial test. If they wanted a test at the 5% level, they might have used $2$ instead of $3.$ The significance level is somewhat arbitrary, but of course in a report you need to say what level you are using.

Comment: They are using a normal test. What I’m not getting it is that the hypothesis which says that probability of success in each trial is p, when translated to normal why the probability of absolute value of z is greater than 3? They conclude that this hypothesis is improbable. In normal curve the probability for each random variable is different right and hence we get a bell-curve. If the probability were same for all then it would be a horizontal line isn’t it? Is that what they conclude?

Comment: Suppose your sample size is $n=36$ and you're testing $H_0:p=1/2$ vs. $H_a: p \ne 1/2.$ You observe $X = 2$ successes. then $z = (2-18)/3 = - 5.33,$ which is outside $(-3,3),$ so you decide $H_0$ must be wrong. // You seem highly invested in some idea that seems to be making this complicated for you. Please just read carefully what @Henry and I have written.

Comment: I get that we can set different significance level. What I’m confused with is how in the book they have concluded that z is outside (-3,3) without using any values or mentioning anything about the significance level.